# "Pinging" a server in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently trying to write a Java application to check if the server of game Archeage is online. I've got the following data:
Archeage EU server IP: 193.105.173.130
Used ports: 80, 1237, 1239, 1250

I managed to check the ports using tool known as **Tcping**, but I want to write a Java application which will have some GUI and will play a sound or do something else when connection is established.

Currently I am stuck with the following code (which isn't working for some reason):

```
package Code;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SocketCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
           "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
           "running the date service on port 80:");
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 80);
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);

        s.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The error messages I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Code.SocketCheck.main(SocketCheck.java:29)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the server code. It isn't my game. I don't even need to receive some sort of predefined messages, all I want to check if the server is up and running.

Comment: @vishalgajera Rubbish. You don't need to know anything about a server except its port to see whether it's running.

Comment: @vishalgajera That's a strange way of putting it. *Either* I'm right *or* I'm wrong: no 'maybe' about it; and it isn't a question of not satisfying me: it is a question of fact., easily determined by analysis or experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `readLine()` and the `BufferedReader` and all that. An HTTP server isn't going to send you anything, it is waiting for you to send a request, and it will time you out eventually. No point in waiting for that, or in doing any I/O at all. The fact that you managed to establish a connection is sufficient proof that the server is up.

Comment: So I'd simply have to use the `is.connected()` method to check if connection has been established?

Comment: You don't even have to do that. With the code you posted, either the `Socket` exists or an exception was thrown. If it exists, it's connected.

Comment: So for proper exception handling I should use `try{}` and `catch{}` blocks instead of `throws`... Well, the solution was so easy that I feel stupid now. Anyways, thanks for such a fast and informative response!

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the thanks, but I haven't said one word about 'proper exception handling'. That's your contribution.

Comment: Sorry, that was a personal thought. I realize that in order to check if server is up I need only the socket, but if I want to do something after checking, exception handling is the way to go in my opinion.